# Wrapping pictures around captions

Tags: captions, minipage, subcaption, wrapfigure, figure-placement

Is it possible to obtain something like

[image]

where the boxes are subfigures? Ideally, the size of the figure on the bottom-right corner would fit to the length of the caption, but I would be happy by manually adjusting it. I thought about using three mini pages, where one would contain the main caption, but not sure if this is the best approach. Any ideas?

**My attempt:** Using `\caption{}` on a single minipage seems to do the trick, although formatting must manually adjusted. Could I raise the caption to the top of minipage?

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.32\textwidth}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.32\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.32\textwidth}
\addtocounter{subfigure}{3}
\centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{}
\end{subfigure}
\end{minipage}
\quad\par\medskip\par\medskip
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum tincidunt vulputate dolor eget volutpat. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Sed mi felis, finibus consectetur laoreet vitae, tincidunt vel nunc. Aenean purus ante, interdum egestas nisi ac, dictum ultricies augue. Ut mollis sapien ut ipsum feugiat, ac convallis nisl dapibus. Proin in mi ut odio ornare scelerisque ac in lorem. Integer non enim accumsan, porta neque ac, euismod elit. Maecenas accumsan velit vitae urna sagittis, vel tincidunt magna pretium.} 
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.4\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[t]{\textwidth}
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{}
\end{subfigure}   
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Would that correspond to the caption of the whole figure? That is, something like "Figure 1. Text" while keeping the subfigure captions "(a), (b),..."? Could you provide an example?

Comment: I realised I can just use `\caption{}` within the minipage (without the subfigure)

Comment: Please post a (pruned) example, once you're finished. Thanks

Comment: Still does not work quite well, as I get a reset of the subfigure caption counter (back to (a)). I will edit the question to show my attempt.

Comment: @MS-SPO Just added it to the question

Comment: Counter is fixed by setting `\addtocounter{subfigure}{3}`

Comment: Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/640344/how-can-i-automatically-force-two-side-by-side-floats-of-any-kind-including-tex

Answer (score 1):

You can set the three top subfigures normally, no `minipage` is necessary. The `minipage` is needed for the caption.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htp]
\centering
\captionsetup{aboveskip=0pt}

\begin{subfigure}[t]{.32\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
  \caption{}
\end{subfigure}\hfil
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.32\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
  \caption{}
\end{subfigure}\hfil
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.32\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
  \caption{}
\end{subfigure}

\bigskip

\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\linewidth}
  \caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
    Vestibulum tincidunt vulputate dolor eget volutpat. Interdum et
    malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Sed mi felis,
    finibus consectetur laoreet vitae, tincidunt vel nunc. Aenean
    purus ante, interdum egestas nisi ac, dictum ultricies augue.
    Ut mollis sapien ut ipsum feugiat, ac convallis nisl dapibus.
    Proin in mi ut odio ornare scelerisque ac in lorem. Integer non
    enim accumsan, porta neque ac, euismod elit. Maecenas accumsan
    velit vitae urna sagittis, vel tincidunt magna pretium.} 
\end{minipage}\hfil
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=T]{example-image}
  \caption{}
\end{subfigure}   
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]