# An automatic parbox

Tags: parbox

I want a box (or minipage) containing some lines to make a specific height.
Vertical spaces can be added automatically to fill between lines to adjust height.
The box has to be as close as possible to the right margin.

I was able to manage this situation using `parbox`, `\vfill` and `\hfill`.
However i have to set the length of the box using the longest line and `\wd`.

Is there a way to make this more automatic ? I had no chance using `pbox`because you can't use `\vfill`there.

```
\newsavebox\mybox
\sbox{\mybox}{hello.world_12345@mail.world}
\newlength{\abc}
\setlength{\abc}{18mm}

%other box of height \abc

\hfill

\parbox[c][\abc][t]{\wd\mybox}{
\faMobile\space 123.456.789
\vfill
\faEnvelope\space hello.world_12345@mail.world
\vfill
\faLocationArrow\space 123 liberty street
\vfill
\faCar\space driving license
\vfill
\faPassport\space working permit
\vfill
}
```

Comment: Looks like a `tabular` to me, rather than a `\parbox`.  Can you complete the document such that it compiles? What is the purpose of \vfill? To which height do you want to spread the lines?

Comment: Please, don't show code snippets. Always show a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964). Without, I would guess: Maybe you can use package `varwidth` and set `\baselineskip` with infinite glue.

Comment: Highly related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/640344/how-can-i-automatically-force-two-side-by-side-floats-of-any-kind-including-tex

Comment: In the minipages  only the  width in mandatory but optionally you can also set  a fixed height. The issue is ensure that the text inside fit well in that space, If you left room for, said ,4 lines of text , but you type  more,  the result will be really ugly, with the excess of text overlapping the text following the minipage.