# Automatically Cropping Images to Match Aspect Ratios in Side-by-Side Figures in LaTeX

Tags: graphics, subfloats, crop-image

I'm working on a document in LaTeX where I need to place two images side-by-side. These images come with different aspect ratios, and I am looking for a way to automatically crop them to appear with the same aspect ratio in the final document.

Here is the basic LaTeX template I'm using to place the images side-by-side:

```latex
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{path/to/first/image}
        \subcaption{First Image}
        \label{fig:first_image}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{path/to/second/image}
        \subcaption{Second Image}
        \label{fig:second_image}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Side-by-Side Images}
    \label{fig:both_images}
\end{figure}
```

My objective is to automatically adjust (crop) these images within LaTeX so that they have matching aspect ratios when displayed. The ideal solution would maintain the height or width (whichever is larger for each image) and crop the other dimension to match the image's aspect ratio with the lower width-to-height ratio.

I know that LaTeX might not be the most efficient tool for image processing, but I'm curious if there is a LaTeX-centric way to achieve this. I'm open to using additional packages or writing some custom commands if necessary.

Comment: Please don't post just code fragments.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz could you be kind to elaborate? I am not sure what is missing from my post. I added the required packages if that's what you are referring to.

Comment: A class and a document environment would ensure that your code fragment would actually be compilable... Even better if you would use images from the `mwe` package

Comment: That being said, did you already have a look at the `adjustbox` package.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Yup, I did try `adjustbox`. I can use it to force the height of the image with the lower aspect ratio. However, it violates the side of the text boundaries. I can also use it to trip the images, but I have to measure and crip manually, wich is not desirable.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, could you be kind enough to elaborate on the `mwe` package? I have never heard of it.

Comment: The `mwe` is a package which provides various test images. If you would use it, we would not get errors because `path/to/first/image` is not found.

Comment: Please search object-aware-cropping  to see why what you asking cannot be done easily in LaTeX. Manual adjustment of cropping will be necessary. Consider rather sizing the images to same height.

Comment: See cat & dog example here  https://cloudinary.com/guides/image-effects/a-full-guide-to-object-aware-cropping

Comment: The only way to match the aspect ratios is to crop the larger dimension in at least one image.  In your example this would mean cropping the one with the greatest height.  Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/640344/how-can-i-automatically-force-two-side-by-side-floats-of-any-kind-including-tex

Comment: @JohnKormylo I developed a PowerShell script that does the job I am looking for. Do you think we can automate it right inside LaTeX? Does LaTeX have some macro/scripting language that we can use to extend the functionality of the markup language?

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to share a workaround that I've developed using a PowerShell script, though it's not a direct LaTeX solution.

I've written a PowerShell script that automatically uses ImageMagick to adjust the aspect ratios of two images. The script calculates the width-to-height ratios of both images, identifies which image has the wider ratio, and then crops this image from the sides to match the aspect ratio of the other image.

Here's a brief overview of how the script works:

1. **Load Images**: The script loads two images whose paths are specified.
2. **Calculate Aspect Ratios**: It uses ImageMagick to get the dimensions of each image and calculates their aspect ratios.
3. **Determine Cropping Requirements**: The script identifies which image needs to be cropped to match the aspect ratio of the other.
4. **Perform Cropping**: The identified image is then cropped accordingly, and the output is saved with a new name indicating it has been cropped.

This PowerShell approach is a workaround that allows preprocessing of images before they are used in a LaTeX document. It helps ensure that the images match aspect ratios when included side-by-side in the LaTeX file.

I'm attaching the PowerShell script here for reference:

```
# Define the paths of the two images
$imagePath1 = "path\to\first\image.jpg"
$imagePath2 = "path\to\second\image.jpg"

# Use ImageMagick to get image dimensions
$dimensions1 = magick identify -format "%wx%h" $imagePath1
$dimensions2 = magick identify -format "%wx%h" $imagePath2



# Extract width and height
$width1, $height1 = $dimensions1 -split 'x' | ForEach-Object { [int]$_ }
$width2, $height2 = $dimensions2 -split 'x' | ForEach-Object { [int]$_ }


# Calculate aspect ratios
$aspectRatio1 = $width1 / $height1
$aspectRatio2 = $width2 / $height2


# Determine which image to crop and calculate new dimensions
if ($aspectRatio1 -gt $aspectRatio2) {
    $newWidth = [math]::Round($height1 * $aspectRatio2)
    $cropAmount = [math]::Round(($width1 - $newWidth) / 2)
    
    $imagePath = $imagePath1
    $height = $height1
}
elseif ($aspectRatio2 -gt $aspectRatio1) {
    $newWidth = [math]::Round($height2 * $aspectRatio1)
    $cropAmount = [math]::Round(($width2 - $newWidth) / 2)

    $imagePath = $imagePath2
    $height = $height2
}

# Assuming $imagePath contains the full path of the image
$imageDirectory = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($imagePath)
$imageFileName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($imagePath)
$imageExtension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($imagePath)

# Constructing new file name with "_cropped" suffix
$newImageName = $imageFileName + "_cropped" + $imageExtension
$newImagePath = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($imageDirectory, $newImageName)


# Crop the image
magick convert $imagePath -crop $newWidth"x"$height"+"$cropAmount"+"0 +repage $newImagePath
```

This script is a practical approach for those comfortable with basic scripting and ImageMagick and can be particularly useful when working with many images.

I hope this workaround might be helpful to others facing similar challenges. I'm still open to any LaTeX-specific solutions if anyone has suggestions!

Comment: All the steps have LaTeX equivalents.  The only remiaining question is how to crop; off the top or bottom, left or right, or an equal amount off both sides?

Comment: @Kormylo  This is the 1 million dollar question, hence my comment in the OP and the link to cloudinary.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Let's consider a simple case just like the one I implemented. Let's assume we will just crop the wider image equally from both sides. Can you be kind to show me how it can be done in LaTeX? I also see that there are LuaTeX, ConTeX, and Perl scripts I am not sure which one is the better choice here.

Comment: How can one aspect ratio be wider than the other? Later you talk about which image is wider, which obviously makes sense, but unless one or other dimension is standard, I can't make sense of the comparison of ratios here.

Answer (score 1):

If you specify the width, then all you need to do is crop the image with the greater height.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \sbox0{\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{example-image-16x10}}%
  \sbox1{\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{example-image-10x16}}%
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
      \ifdim\ht0>\ht1\relax
        \edef\crop{\the\dimexpr 0.5\ht0-0.5\ht1}%
        \adjustbox{clip,trim=0pt {\crop} 0pt \crop}{\usebox0}
      \else
        \usebox0
      \fi
      \subcaption{First Image}
      \label{fig:first_image}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
      \ifdim\ht1>\ht0\relax
        \edef\crop{\the\dimexpr 0.5\ht1-0.5\ht0}%
        \adjustbox{clip,trim=0pt {\crop} 0pt \crop}{\usebox1}
      \else
        \usebox1
      \fi
      \subcaption{Second Image}
      \label{fig:second_image}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Side-by-Side Images}
    \label{fig:both_images}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot visualize the utility of an automatic crop with images of different sizes width and heights, as  this way you cannot have control of what is lost in each image.

If  the main point is maintain the same height within (not between) each pair of images  and always stick both margins and fill the 90% of the text width, i.e., without differents gaps in each pair, but is not a must equal widths in both sides, my suggestion is just scale without crop anything.  The next MWE test a macro to make this automatically, for clarity, without using subfigures nor floats.

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[columnsep=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{settobox}
\usepackage{calc}
\parindent0pt
\parskip1em

\newlength{\WA}
\newlength{\HA}
\newlength{\WB}
\newlength{\HB}
\newsavebox{\boxA}
\newsavebox{\boxB}
\newlength{\XY}

\newcommand\img[2]{
\sbox{\boxA}{\includegraphics{#1}}\settoboxwidth{\WA}{\boxA}
\settoboxheight{\HA}{\boxA}\sbox{\boxB}{\includegraphics{#2}}
\settoboxwidth{\WB}{\boxB}\settoboxheight{\HB}{\boxB}
\par\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
\includegraphics[width=\dimexpr\WA*\HB/\HA,height=\HB,keepaspectratio]{#1}
\setlength{\XY}{\dimexpr((\WA*\HB/\HA)+\WB)}\hspace{.05\XY}%
\includegraphics[width=\WB,height=\HB,keepaspectratio]{#2}\par}}

\begin{document}

\img{example-image-16x9}{example-image-16x10}
\img{example-image-9x16}{example-image-10x16}
\img{example-image-16x9}{example-image-10x16}
\img{example-image-9x16}{example-image-16x10}
\img{example-image}{example-image-1x1}
\img{example-image-golden}{example-image-9x16}
\img{example-image-golden-upright}{example-image-9x16}
\img{example-image-golden-upright}{example-image-1x1}
\img{example-image-1x1}{example-image-golden-upright}

\end{document}
```