Caption of a figure aligned to right-hand margin with `minipage`
I would place the caption immediately to the right of each figure. With the use of
 \begin{minipage}[c]{0.67\textwidth} 

I was able to obtain a caption to the right of the figure, but I have a situation where the caption is completely aligned to the right-hand margin. For example:

\documentclass{report}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
    \usepackage{nicefrac}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \begin{minipage}[c]{0.67\textwidth}
        XX\dotfill XX
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[c]{0.3\textwidth}
    \caption{
      Illustrazione qualitativa dell'andamento asintotico delle incertezze
      statistiche e sistematiche in funzione del numero di misure $n$ (cfr. la
      sezione~\ref{sec:andamento_asintotico_stat}). Mentre l'incertezza statistica
      diminuisce come $\nicefrac{1}/{\sqrt{n}}$, quella sistematica è costante,
      per cui esiste un regime in cui continuare ad eseguire misure non ha
      alcun beneficio in termini di accuratezza della misura.
      }
    \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
  \end{document}

As you can see, the output returns an image with a caption fully aligned to the right-hand margin. What solution can be adopted to insert the caption to the right of the figure, but without aligning it to the right margin, so that it is more fluid and visually elegant, and not forced as in this case?

since you are asking about the caption why do you have all this tikz code in the question you should replace the entire pgfpicture with X  and remove all the pgf related packages.

@DavidCarlisle In what sense "replace the entire pgfpicture with X"? Shouldn't I put a figure in the code?

Your example is completely unreasonable to ask anyone to trace (you are not asking about pgf at all so why post 100s of lines of unrelated code (and why use low level pgf rather than tikz anyway)  I put a more reasonable example at the end but you should delete your original example. You are hyphenating  Italian using English hyphenation rules, that will not end well, you need \usepackage[italian]{babel}

@DavidCarlisle OK, I'm going to delete my original example. P.S. What do you mean with "low level pgf rather than tikz"?

search this website for how many times you see pgfpicture and  \pgfpathlineto etc (almost never) compared to using tikzpicture and \draw, or for plotting graphs pgfplots (you load both of these but don't use them)

it isn't clear what you are asking for, you could have a raggedright caption  is that what you are asking?

@DavidCarlisle I don't know. What should I do?

we can not tell you what to do if you do not say clearly what you want, perhaps just telling latex that you are writing in Italian will already give you a layout you like, I don't know,

@DavidCarlisle No, I meant: you asked me whether raggedright was what I was looking for. What commands should I use to find out? Anyway, I would just like a normal caption to the right of a figure.

You have a normal caption to the right of the figure you are asking for a non standard layout but it's not clear what. To get raggedright you can use \raggedright (I posted an example) but it is not clear if that is what you meant by "without aligning it to the right margin"

@DavidCarlisle It happened that because the caption was attached to the right margin, there was a lot of space between the figure and the beginning of the caption, to the point that it looked like a completely disconnected body. This is what I want to avoid.

well you chose 67% of the width for the figure and 30% of the width for the caption, so you can give less space to the figure and more to the caption and have a smaller gap

@DavidCarlisle Yes, I had tried this, but it wasn't enough because it moved the caption to the middle of the figure, whereas I wanted it to start at the top end of the figure.

no changing those widths won't change the vertical position  it will just make the caption start further left and be wider

you are using vertically centred minipages, perhaps you want \begin{minipage}[t] in both cases I updated the answer

@DavidCarlisle Thanks, but strangely, the caption, although correctly aligned to the right, appears shifted down, even below the lower end of the figure.

@DavidCarlisle OK, I solved by decreasing \vspace. Thank you.

Possible relate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/640344/how-can-i-automatically-force-two-side-by-side-floats-of-any-kind-including-tex

It's not really clear what you are asking for, I added babel so that Italian hyphenation rules are used and you have a chance of reasonable line breaking, then in the second example I added \raggedright so that the text is not fully justified to the right margin.
But based on comments, perhaps you are looking for the third option with [t] rather than [c] and more space allocated to the caption and less to the figure.

\documentclass{report}
 \usepackage[italian]{babel}% you need this
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
    \usepackage{nicefrac}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \begin{minipage}[c]{0.67\textwidth}
    XX\dotfill XX

    XX\dotfill XX
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[c]{0.3\textwidth}
    \caption[short text]{
      Illustrazione qualitativa dell'andamento asintotico delle incertezze
      statistiche e sistematiche in funzione del numero di misure $n$ (cfr. la
      sezione~\ref{sec:andamento_asintotico_stat}). Mentre l'incertezza statistica
      diminuisce come $\nicefrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$, quella sistematica è costante,
      per cui esiste un regime in cui continuare ad eseguire misure non ha
      alcun beneficio in termini di accuratezza della misura.
      }
    \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}

      \begin{figure}
    \begin{minipage}[c]{0.67\textwidth}
      XX\dotfill XX

      XX\dotfill XX
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[c]{0.3\textwidth}
    \caption[short text]{\raggedright
      Illustrazione qualitativa dell'andamento asintotico delle incertezze
      statistiche e sistematiche in funzione del numero di misure $n$ (cfr. la
      sezione~\ref{sec:andamento_asintotico_stat}). Mentre l'incertezza statistica
      diminuisce come $\nicefrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$, quella sistematica è costante,
      per cui esiste un regime in cui continuare ad eseguire misure non ha
      alcun beneficio in termini di accuratezza della misura.
      }
    \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}


    
      \begin{figure}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.57\textwidth}
      XX\dotfill XX

      XX\dotfill XX
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
    \vspace{-10pt}
    \caption[short text]{\raggedright
      Illustrazione qualitativa dell'andamento asintotico delle incertezze
      statistiche e sistematiche in funzione del numero di misure $n$ (cfr. la
      sezione~\ref{sec:andamento_asintotico_stat}). Mentre l'incertezza statistica
      diminuisce come $\nicefrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$, quella sistematica è costante,
      per cui esiste un regime in cui continuare ad eseguire misure non ha
      alcun beneficio in termini di accuratezza della misura.
      }
    \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}

  \end{document}

